# How to compare two pairs of columns in two different files and print matches merged horizontally (preference for BASH or AWK)?

Tags: awk, text-processing

I'm trying to compare two tab-separated files by matching two different pairs of columns. After a match, I'd like to print the matching lines from both files merged horizontally (that is, side-by-side, akin to BASH paste). The files have 12 columns.

Looking everywhere I found no similar questions, which honestly makes me worry I might be overthinking the issue.

Simply put, the goal would be to "match column 1 (in file 1) with column 2 (in file 2)" and "column 2 (in file 1) with column 1 (in file 2)" and only then print the respective matching lines side-by-side.

An example:

File1.tsv

```
1   A   ExtraInfo
2   B   ExtraInfo
3   C   ExtraInfo
4   D   ExtraInfo
5   E   ExtraInfo
```

File2.tsv

```
D   4   ExtraInfo
B   7   ExtraInfo
E   9   ExtraInfo
C   3   ExtraInfo
A   1   ExtraInfo
```

Desired output:

```
1   A   ExtraInfo   A   1   ExtraInfo
3   C   ExtraInfo   C   3   ExtraInfo
4   D   ExtraInfo   D   4   ExtraInfo
```

Although I couldn't find anyone with the same issue, I did find some similar questions that led me to think awk would probably be my best bet. Unfortunately I'm still a complete potato with it, so my attempts are limited to trying to adapt code from similar questions.

I tried the following, to no avail:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1 && a[$1]=$2;next} {print $0,a[$0]}' file1 file2
```

Nonetheless, if someone can only lend a hand in another language default to Ubuntu I'll still be thankful.

Comment: looks like a query with two index columns

Comment: On the assumption that this is a learning exercise, I won't give you a complete answer (please tell me if I'm wrong on this) but I'd suggest you look up the Unix `join` command, which is usable from `bash`.

Comment: `in another language default to the GNOME terminal` A "terminal" doesn't determine language you are using... It's like a printer doesn't determine if you print documents in english or any other language, it just prints. A terminal just displays.

Comment: This seems to work: https://repl.it/repls/ThoughtfulGlamorousLocks

Comment: @Simon No this is not a learning exercise. Sorry I should have provided more details but didn't want to clutter the post. I'm trying to process tabular output from a protein alignment algorithm. I have a semi-automated method, but I was trying to speed things where possible. About `join`, I'll try to explore it thanks! Can it merge lines on multiple fields in the same file? I really need to match the 4 columns I mentioned. Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: @KamilCuk Sorry about the lapse! I meant to say in any of the languages that come default with Linux (bash, awk, perl, etc.) and even that I guess I meant specifically Ubuntu. Thanks for the correction, just don't take it too personally.

Comment: @alecxs Sorry if it's an obvious question, but could you elaborate? Even pointing towards some literature or manual would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please revise the question to indicate that [the *.tsv* files have 12 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62505137/how-to-compare-two-pairs-of-columns-in-two-different-files-and-print-matches-mer/62506879#comment110554775_62506879).  The sample output shows an example for 3 columns.  Please revise the sample output to show what should be done with the other 9 columns in each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE**: After OP provided more details (eg, files have 12 columns) I've added @karafka's suggested edits into my answer.

---

Assumptions:

- each 1st/2nd column pair is unique within a file (ie, at most one line matches from each file)
- 3rd column does not contain any tabs (ie, each tab-delimited file has a total of 3 columns)
- output is ordered by 1st and 2nd columns (ie, not attempting to maintain any ordering based on the content of the source files)

One `awk/sort` solution:

```
awk -F"\t" '                                          # input delimiter is a tab
BEGIN         { OFS=FS }                              # output delimiter is also a tab
NR==FNR       { a[$1,$2]=$0 ; next }                  # store first file line in array using fields 1 & 2 as index 
($2,$1) in a  { print a[$2,$1],$0 }                   # if array entry exists with first 2 fields as index (in reverse order) then print array element==matching-line-from-file1 and $0==current-line-from-file2 to stdout
' file1.tsv file2.tsv | sort                          # sort output from awk [optional]
```

**NOTE**: Remove comments to declutter the code.

Running the above against the sample data files generates:

```
1       A       ExtraInfo       A       1       ExtraInfo
3       C       ExtraInfo       C       3       ExtraInfo
4       D       ExtraInfo       D       4       ExtraInfo
```

Comment: if `$3` is zero the condition will fail, better to replace with (`$2,$1) in a`

Comment: @karakfa; yeah, I was thinking of the `... in a` approach but wasn't 100% sure about the multi-index aspect; updated the answer; thanks

Comment: @markp-fuso Thanks for the reply! About your assumptions (and sorry I failed to mention those details): -1st: Each pair is unique in each file. -2nd: There aren't only just 3 columns, sorry! The files actually have 12 tab-separated columns, they just weren't important for finding the match. -3rd: The order is actually irrelevant, as long as the lines are 100% properly aligned. Sorry about that as well, my example could have been better.

Comment: for that change to `a[$1,$2]=$0`in the second line and `print a[$2,$1],$0` in the next line.

Comment: @DiogoL.A. re: 12 columns ... I've updated the answer to include karakfa's suggested edits (storing/printing $0 == entire line); that should (knock on wood) address your additional details (???)

Comment: @markp-fuso Thank you so much Mark, it worked! And such a simple and well explained solution too! I was wondering, if the pairs were not unique, but their order mattered, would it be possible to include a `''seen[$1]` command in the code so that it only kept the first match for column 1, file 1, (considered the best one)?

Comment: @DiogoL.A. yes, that's likely possible; I'd suggest a) taking the above code and trying to modify it to do what you want and if you run into a road block then b) open a new question making sure to provide as much detail as possible (sample data, expected output, what you've tried)

Comment: @markp-fuso Thanks, I'll try messing around with it!

Answer (score 2):

1. Extract column 1&2 from both files into a separate column
2. Join files.

[The following works on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/RashDistortedPercent#main.sh):

```
join -t$'\t' -14 -24 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3 <(
    awk -v F='\t' -v OFS='\t' '{NF++;$4=$2$1}1' File1.tsv |
    sort -k4) <(
    awk -v F='\t' -v OFS='\t' '{NF++;$4=$1$2}1' File2.tsv |
    sort -k4)
```

If you want to preserve the sorting order of the first file, number the lines in first file with `nl`, do the joining, then re-sort on line numbers with `sort -k1` and remove line numbers with `cut`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry, I failed to mention thinking it was irrelevant, but the files actually have 12 tab-separated columns! I see where that would change the `join` options, but what about the ´awk`part?

Comment: The `NF++` increment the count of columns and `$4=` assigns to the last column. I guess it could be generalized by just `$NF=` (or even `$(NF++)=`, ach that awk)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sort`, `paste`, and *GNU* `egrep`:

```
paste File1.tsv <(sort File2.tsv) | 
egrep '^(\w)\W*(\w)\W*(\w*\W*){1}\2\W*\1\W'
```

Output:

```
1   A   ExtraInfo   A   1   ExtraInfo
3   C   ExtraInfo   C   3   ExtraInfo
4   D   ExtraInfo   D   4   ExtraInfo
```

---

How it works:

Notice how the output is, (at least for the matching items), a list of partial palindromes -- but the lines to omit are *not* palindromes.

First `sort` the unsorted *File2.tsv*, then `paste` the two files together.

*GNU* `grep` provides back expressions that enable searching for palindromic strings.

If there are more columns, change the `{1}` to however many *extra* columns there are.  So if there were **12** columns in each *.tsv* files, change the `{1}` to `{10}`, like so:

```
paste File1.tsv <(sort File2.tsv) | 
egrep '^(\w)\W*(\w)\W*(\w*\W*){10}\2\W*\1\W'
```

Comment: Sorry @agc, but running that command returned empty. Could it be because my files actually have 12 columns (sorry I forgot to mention it, by the way)?

Comment: @DiogoL.A., See revised answer.